# sqlite connection with c# XamlParseException

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, connection

I have some difficult to make a connection with my existing sqlite db in c#. I want to make it for a WPF application.

This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using Finisar.SQLite; 

namespace Ebios_WPF
{

/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        // We use these three SQLite objects:
        Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
        Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

        // create a new database connection:
        sqlite_conn = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=existingDB.db; Version=3;");

        // open the connection:
        sqlite_conn.Open();
```

When I put an existing sqlite DB in argument I have an XamlParseException:

```
sqlite_conn = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=existingDB.db; Version=3;");
```

but if i create a new database it works :

```
sqlite_conn = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=NewDB.db; Version=3;New=True;");
```

Thank you for your help :)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue (and same error message) and found that sqlite.interop.dll was not automatically output/copied to where it should be in the main WPF project.

I have a class project ("Repository"), which uses System.Data.Sqlite.Core from Nuget. When I build that project, it outputs to it's bin\Debug\ directory, and it creates two sub-directories: "x64" and "x86" with sqlite.interop.dll in each. These directories are needed in the main (WPF) project, but are not moved there on build. So, to manage this, I've manually created a x64 and x86 folder in the Debug and Release bin directories of the main WPF and copy over sqlite.interop.dll. I've added this to my post build like so (first create the folders x64 and x86). "Repository" is the name of my project where the Sqlite Nuget package was installed.

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)Repository\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\x64\*.*" "$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\x64\" /Y 
copy "$(ProjectDir)Repository\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\x86\*.*" "$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\x86\" /Y
```

I was able to resolve this in visual studio, but when I went to release the software and create an .msi, I forgot about the directories and had to also create them for my .msi.

I haven't tried it, but maybe you can just install Sqlite Nuget package into your WPF project.